# Visual C++ how do you debug a button click?

Tags: c++, .net, winforms

I'm extremely new to visual c++, I thought that having the debugger be able to debug a button click would be as simple as vb/c# .net but it's clearly not :)  I'm having difficulty finding anything online explaining how you debug visual C++ button clicks.  Since there's no events like in VB, how does one go about doing this?

Comment: What GUI framework are you using MFC, WinApi, WTL, QT, Wx ? There's just not enough to go on here.

Comment: Are you using actually using C++/CLI and .Net? Or is this an MFC application? Regardless...you just put a breakpoint on the line to debug a "button click".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the framework in question, or really the language in question, when debugging an application using Visual Studio you simply place a breakpoint on the line in question.

[image: Line to stop at when debugging]

You can place a breakpoint by hitting F9 on the line you would like to stop at or by right clicking on the line and going to Breakpoint > Insert Breakpoint.

[image: Breakpoint Context Menu]

That being said, if you have no code to "handle" (in the general sense of the term, as I'm not certain what framework you're using) a button click, then you will have no code to insert a breakpoint into.